# convert portion of code into a function php

Tags: php

This is probably very easy to do but for some reason I can't seem to figure this out. Let's say I have code like this:

```
$elements = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$myValues = array(
    'values' => array(
        'a' => array(
            'xx' => 3,
            'yy' => ''
        ),
        'b' => array(
            'xx' => '',
            'yy' => ''
        ),
        'c' => array(
            'xx' => 8.4,
            'yy' => ''
        ),
        'd' => array(
            'xx' => 18.4,
            'yy' => ''
            )
        )
);

foreach($elements as $elem)
{
    if($myValues['values'][$elem]['xx'] != '')
    {
        if($myValues['values'][$elem]['xx'] < 6)
        {
            $myValues['values'][$elem]['yy'] =  'less than 6';
        }
        elseif($myValues['values'][$elem]['xx'] >= 6 && $myValues['values'][$elem]['xx'] < 15)
        {
            $myValues['values'][$elem]['yy'] =  'between 6 and 16';
        }
        else
        {
            $myValues['values'][$elem]['yy'] = 'greater than 15';
        }

            testFunc($myValues['values'][$elem]['xx']); // This is how I would call my function once I replace the code above
    }
}
```

As you can see here what I'm trying to do is to change the value of `$myValues['values'][$elem]['yy']` based on some conditions. What I want to do is to replace the `if elseif else` section of codes by a function that performs the same action.

I tried something like:

```
function testFunc($xx)
{
    if($xx < 6)
    {
        $yy = 'less than 6';
    }
    elseif($xx >= 6 && $xx < 15)
    {
        $yy =  'between 6 and 16';
    }
    else
    {
        $yy = 'greater than 15';
    }

    return $yy;
}
```

But obviously this won't work because I'm not changing the value of `$myValues['values'][$elem]['yy']` inside my function.

**NOTE** I really want to pass ONLY the value of `$myValues['values'][$elem]['xx']` inside my function and return the changed value of `$myValues['values'][$elem]['yy']`.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you use `testFunc` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: re-reading the question, I seem to have misunderstood it at first glance. There doesn't seem to be a need for references here. Would this not work?

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $myValues['values'][$element]['yy'] = testFunc($myValues['values'][$element]['xx']);
}
```

Equally, if `$elements` is always the same as `array_keys($myValues['values'])`, you *could* use references:

```
foreach ($myValues['values'] as &$value) {
    $value['yy'] = testFunc($value['xx']);
}
```

Comment: `$myValues['values'][$elem]['xx']` is what my function takes, but what is modified (based on some conditions) is `$myValues['values'][$elem]['yy']`

Comment: I knew it was easy (my brain is tired, I need a break lol). I was calling my function but I forgot to put the value that I was trying to change equal to the result of my function call. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### function testFunc()

```
function testFunc(&$arr) {
  foreach ($arr['values'] as &$values) {
    if ($values['xx'] != '') {
      if ($values['xx'] < 6)
        $values['yy'] = 'less than 6';
      elseif ($values['xx'] >= 6 && $values['xx'] <= 15)
        $values['yy'] = 'between 6 and 15';
      else
        $values['yy'] = 'greater than 15';
      }
    }
  }
```

### Usage:

```
testFunc($myValues);
print_r($myValues);
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
  [values] => Array
    (

      [a] => Array
        (
          [xx] => 3
          [yy] => less than 6
        )

      [b] => Array
        (
          [xx] => 
          [yy] => 
        )

      [c] => Array
        (
          [xx] => 8.4
          [yy] => between 6 and 15
        )

      [d] => Array
        (
          [xx] => 18.4
          [yy] => greater than 15
        )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($elements as $elem){
    $xx = $myValues['values'][$elem]['xx'];
    if(empty($xx)) continue;
    $myValues['values'][$elem]['yy'] = testFunc($xx);
}

function testFunc($xx){
    if($xx < 6) return 'less than 6';
    return ($xx > 15) ? 'greater than 15' : 'between 6 and 16';
}
```